# How to launch application after each test Junit5 TestFX

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5, testfx

I'm writing an application test with Junit5 and TestFX.
My intention is that the main test class relaunches the application after each test. As far as I know, I shall use the annotation @BeforeEach, and it didn't work for me.

Here is my test class:

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class MainTest extends ApplicationTest implements FxRobotInterface {
Logger loggerGuiTesting = LoggerManager.getInstance().getLogger(LoggerType.GUI_TESTING);

@BeforeEach
@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) {
    StartMain.getInstance();
    this.loggerGuiTesting.log(Level.INFO, "Application starts!");
}

@AfterAll
public void endApplication() {
    new ExitGuiTest().run(); // That's my internal test framework
}

@Test
public void atestIfOpeningScreenIsThere() {
    verifyThat("#imageViewSplashScreenLogo", NodeMatchers.isNotNull());
    verifyThat("#progressBarSplashScreen", NodeMatchers.isNotNull());
    verifyThat("#labelSplashScreenVersion", NodeMatchers.isNotNull());
    verifyThat("#labelSplashScreenDate", NodeMatchers.isNotNull());
    this.loggerGuiTesting.log(Level.INFO, "testIfOpeningScreenIsThere, succeeded!");
}

@Test
public void btestIfRadioButtonOneExist() {
    assertThat("#sourcesOneRadioButton", is("#sourcesOneRadioButton"));
this.loggerGuiTesting.log(Level.INFO, "testIfRadioButtonOneExist, succeeded!");
    }

@Test
    public cnextTest() {
        new StartAnotherGuiTest().run();
        this.loggerGuiTesting.log(Level.INFO, "anotherTest, succeeded!");
    }

}
```

The question is: how can I relaunch the application after each test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to answer without taking a look at the StartMain class. It looks like you are using a singleton pattern there. If thats the case I would create a  new method in StartMain that sets the singleton instance to null so when getInstance is called again, it has to be re-created:

```
@After //This should be executed after each test
public void destroyApp()
{
    StartMain.getInstance().destroy();
}
```